# Divisibility of higher power polynomials

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, factoring, binomial-theorem

I am stuck with this problem suggested to me by a friend . The problem reads,
The power of $x^2+xy+y^2$ by which the polynomial $(x+y)^7-x^7-y^7$ is divisible are ?
I tried it by writing $x^7+y^7$ expansion and simplifying the polynomials in factors but that doesn't help as the resulting expression is ugly . Someone kindly suggest a method to solve this problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you search for $n$ such that $(x+y)^7 - x^7 - y^7 = (x^2+xy+y^2)^n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert this problem to a one-variable problem by dividing a suitable power of $\ x$. Consider $$\ f(t)={(1+t)}^{7}-1-{t}^{7}$$ Note that $\ f(\omega)=0$. This implies that $\ {t}^{2}+t+1$ divides $\ f(t)$. Now, if the second power of $\ {t}^{2}+t+1$ is also a factor of $\ f(t)$, then $\ f'(\omega)=0$. Can you proceed?

I'll continue. $$\ f'(t)=7{(1+t)}^{6}-7{t}^{6}$$
Putting $\ t=\omega$, we have $$\ f'(\omega)=0$$ Hence the second power of $\ {t}^{2}+t+1$ divides $\ f(t)$. If the third power also divides $\ f(t)$ then $$\ f''(\omega)=0$$
$$\ f''(t)=42\left({(1+t)}^{5}-t^5\right)$$
Note that $\ f''(\omega) \neq 0$. Hence, the highest power of $\ {t}^{2}+t+1$ that divides $\ f(t)$ is $\ 2$. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) @ Vishnu Kadiri

Answer (score 1):

By the Binomial theorem we obtain:
$$(x+y)^7-x^7-y^7=7xy(x^5+3x^4y+5x^3y^2+5x^2y^3+3xy^4+y^5)=$$
$$=7xy(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4+3xy(x^2-xy+y^2)+5x^2y^2)=$$
$$=7xy(x+y)(x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+2xy^3+y^4)=7xy(x+y)(x^2+xy+y^2)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) @Michael Rozenberg

Comment: @Crazy over Maths You are welcome!